# Two Windows Server domains, two users, same permissions

Tags: windows-server-2008, active-directory, domain, domain-controller, users

I work for a small company, owned by a bigger one. I have a user in my parent company's domain: `DomainA\MyUser`.

Now we have bought our own server and want our own domain. I have created a user in the new domain, with the same user name as the old user name: `DomainB\MyUser`. This user is network administrator in `DomainB`.

My computer is still in `DomainA`. When I log in there as `DomainA\MyUser`, I get all permissions of `DomainB\MyUser` on the new server (which is domain controller of `DomainB` and not connected to `DomainA`).

This even if I set `DomainB\MyUser` as inactive.

How is this possible??

#### [EDIT 2010-07-06]

Doesn't work with disabled user in `DomainB`. Last when I tried I forgot to kill all sessions for the user.

Screenshots when I use remote desktop: http://www.enalog.se/files/index.html <sup>(dead)</sup>

Details:

- `NEMOQ_AD` is the old domain.
- `ENALOG` is the new domain.

  - `VOLDEMORT` is domain controller of `ENALOG`.
- `Peter` is the user

#### [EDIT 2010-07-08]

When I type the user as `MyUser@DomainA`, I cannot log in. Why does it work with `DomainA\MyUser`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## This is an NTLM feature that automatically tries a different DOMAIN name from what you entered.

Every login in your screenshots is the user `ENALOG\Peter`, not `NEMOQ_AD\Peter`.

It doesn't matter that you're **typing** the domain `NEMOQ_AD\Peter`, since `NEMOQ_AD` is not a domain that `ENALOG` trusts. (See below.)

Notice that you don't see `NAMOQ_AD` anywhere once you've connected to `Voldemort`.

### NTLM pass-through authentication

NTLM supports something called [pass-through authentication](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/102716).  The important bit of the article is here: (emphasis added)

> - If the domain name specified is not trusted by the domain, **the authentication request is processed on the computer being connected to as if the domain name specified were that domain name**. NetLogon does not differentiate between a nonexistent domain, an untrusted domain, and an incorrectly typed domain name.

#### Example for your net share use

What is happening is the following:

1. `Voldemort` receives a request to authenticate the user `NEMOQ_AD\Peter`.
2. `Voldemort` sees that `NEMOQ_AD` is neither its own domain nor any domain that it trusts.
3. Voldemort tries to authenticate the user `ENALOG\Peter` instead.
4. Since you entered the password for `ENALOG\Peter` (as you said in another comment), authentication succeeds.

#### Re. net shares in general

When you are accessing the drive share, you have to be using NTLM (any attempt to use Kerberos will fail because `ENALOG` doesn't trust `NAMOQ_AD`) using pass-through authentication, which allows you to access network shares without typing a password.  This works only when you are using identically-named accounts with an identical passwords on the two machines.

#### Re. RDP

When you enter a password when using *Remote Desktop*, it's behaving exactly as if you had tried to log in as `ENALOG\Peter` instead of `NEMOQ_AD\Peter`, and using whatever password you typed in.  This way, if you type `Peter` as your username, the local computer sends `NEMOQ_AD\Peter` since that's the only domain it knows about, but the remote computer decides to try `ENALOG\Peter` instead.

#### Re. SSMS

I assume SQL Server Management Studio is using one strategy or the other (probably the second one), I don't know exact details of its implementation and don't have two domains lying around to test it.

Comment: So...

"I don't know who you are. I don't trust you. I guess you are this one instead. Now I trust you."

I'm not experienced in servers, but to me that's a very strange behavior and a security risk.

Anyhow, at least this tells me why it behaves this way and if I use different passwords it shouldn't be any problems.

Comment: Pass-through authentication is the equivalent of sending over the password to the remote machine (without actually having to do so), so really you are supplying Voldemort with the password for ENALOG\Peter, and you just happened to have typed it a few minutes earlier while you were logging in as NEMOQ_AD\Peter.  NTLM assumes that if it can prove you have the same password on two identically-named accounts, then it's probably OK to go ahead and not make you explicitly type credentials again.  So, it's more like spell-check for your username.

Comment: It's not a security risk because you DO know the password for the remote computer.  The only time this would be the "wrong" thing to do would be if the accounts ENALOG\Peter and NEMOQ_AD\Peter represented different people who just happen to have identical passwords.  Not very likely in the grand scheme of things.

Answer (score 0):

That's not possible. Something is misconfigured.

Comment: I haven't done any configuration except adding an administrator and a couple of normal users in DomainB.

Comment: Where can I configure this?

Comment: Does a trust exist between NEMOQ_AD and ENALOG?

Are the passwords for NEMOQ_AD\peter and ENALOG\peter identical?

Are there any warnings or errors thrown in the application, system, or security event logs on the ENALOG domain controller at the time of authentication?

Comment: No trust is configured. No warnings or errors.


I've played some more with the passwords:

Remote desktop doesn't seem to care about the domain. I can log in with NEMOQ_AD\Peter and the password of ENALOG\Peter.

With UNC I cannot go to the server's folders at all if the passwords are different (only works if I log in as ENALOG\Peter, as it should be). When the passwords are identical NEMOQ_AD\Peter behaves just like ENALOG\Peter.

Comment: In that case, I don't see any problems here; authentication is working as designed. If NEMOQ_AD\Peter and ENALOG\Peter should not have access to each other's resources, then either 1) their passwords need to be different, or 2) a trust needs to be created between domains.

Comment: I failed to read the post from Stephen Jennings before responding to your comment; he comprehensively describes this. Apologies.

Answer (score 0):

Can you be more specific? What do you mean you get the same permissions? Are you referring to file and folder permissions? What do you mean you set the userB account as inactive? There's no such thing as "inactive". Do you mean that you set the userB account to disabled?

Comment: Yes, I mean disabled (language issue :)).

When I sit at the computer in DomainA with DomainA\MyUser, I have for example full rights in \\ServerB\c$. I have also made DomainB\MyUser a sysadmin in a MS SQL Server which also applies to  DomainA\MyUser.

Comment: DomainA\MyUser can also use remote desktop to connect to the new server and then gets same rights on the server as DomainB\MyUser.

Answer (score 0):

Stephen Jennings already answered it thoroughly but I'm just thinking, out of curiosity alone, what's the reason for the separate domain in this case?

There are many good reasons but generally maintaining multiple domains is a hassle and it doesn't sound like anyone will be able to manage it and instead just create the typical overhead associated with sustaining multiple domains for a group of people.

Why not incorporate the new server in the existing domain, using configuration to limit its resources to your company. Do you need to access resources at the parent company? Are the parent company administrators not trusted?

Comment: No, they are not trusted. The domains must be separate.

Having two separate domains I think should be easier than not to separate them.